# How to write shellcode in c?

Tags: c, shell, shellcode

i try to write shell code in file using c , but after execute the program i found the ASCII code not shell code in the file . 
this is the code :

```
FILE *shell;
    shell = fopen("shell.txt", "w");
    fprintf(shell,"shell = '\xbd\x7f\x94' \n");
    fclose(shell);
```

Comment: What would you expect your file to contain, if not what you put in it?

Comment: Are you trying to execute the shell code you write in file?

Answer (score 1):

In C to print a backslash you need to escape it, as it *is* the escape character.

So to print

```
shell = '\xbd\x7f\x94' <LF>
```

specify

```
"shell = '\\xbd\\x7f\\x94' \n"
```

instead.